# How to select an element that was created in a for loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, closures, jquery-hover

I've dynamically loaded lots of pairs of elements onto my page.  Each pair has a descriptor in a list, and a highlighter overlaid on an image.

What I want is when a user hovers over the list item, that the other element is highlighted.

My current code below only ever highlights the last element in the `.viewer`, no matter which list item I hover over.

What's the best approach for handling this?

```
for (i = 0; i < Ajax.length; ++i) {
    var listid = 'listitem-'+i;
    var mapid = 'mapitem-'+i;

    $('.list').append('<div id="'+listid+'">Lots of Text</div>');
    $('.viewer').append('<div id="'+mapid+'">Here It Is</div>');

    $('#'+listid).hover(function(){
        $('#'+mapid).toggleClass('highlight');
    });
}
```

Comment: @susheel - there's no need for a fiddle.  The issue is explained clearly and all the code required is posted above.

Comment: still it makes the helpers job easier, so its always good to have a fiddle so that your questions get solved soon

Comment: I don't see why anyone would downvote this.  It explains the problem and the code shows it 100%.  Both myself and MrCode were able to answer it without the requested jsfiddle.  Whoever downvoted this question clearly does not understand this simple problem.

Comment: Here is fiddle of my code above if you want it http://jsfiddle.net/u2N36/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mapid` has the last value assigned to it by the time the hover event handler is fired, so you need to make sure you have the relevant value.

Try putting the hover assignment inside an enclosure...

```
for (i = 0; i < Ajax.length; ++i) {
    var listid = 'listitem-'+i;
    var mapid = 'mapitem-'+i;

    $('.list').append('<div id="'+listid+'">Lots of Text</div>');
    $('.viewer').append('<div id="'+mapid+'">Here It Is</div>');

    (function(listid, mapid) {
        $('#'+listid).hover(function(){
            $('#'+mapid).toggleClass('highlight');
        });
    })(listid, mapid);
}
```

An alternative method would be to store the associated map ID with the list item, like this...

```
for (i = 0; i < Ajax.length; ++i) {
    var listid = 'listitem-'+i;
    var mapid = 'mapitem-'+i;

    $('.list').append('<div id="'+listid+'">Lots of Text</div>');
    $('.viewer').append('<div id="'+mapid+'">Here It Is</div>');

    $('#'+listid).data("associated-map-id", mapid);

    $('#'+listid).hover(function(){
        $('#'+$(this).data("associated-map-id")).toggleClass('highlight');
    });
}
```

Either will work and they'll give the same end result.  Just choose what you prefer :)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work!  My original code: http://jsfiddle.net/u2N36/  and your code: http://jsfiddle.net/QnCL2/

Answer (score 0):

Move the hover handler into a closure, passing `listid` and `mapid` as arguments. This creates the variables in a new scope where they don't get affected by the `mapid` and `listid` that get overwritten in the higher scope.

```
for (i = 0; i < Ajax.length; ++i) {
    var listid = 'listitem-'+i;
    var mapid = 'mapitem-'+i;

    $('.list').append('<div id="'+listid+'">Lots of Text</div>');
    $('.viewer').append('<div id="'+mapid+'">Here It Is</div>');

    (function(listid, mapid){
        $('#'+listid).hover(function(){
            $('#'+mapid).toggleClass('highlight');
        });
    })(listid, mapid);
}
```